# Maven run submodule from Netbeans

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, exec-maven-plugin

I want to build an application with Maven. Currently I have the following setup:

- Two projects; Project A and Project B.
- Project B depends on A (with the dependency tag in the pom).
- The main Class is in project B.

I have included everything in Netbeans. Now when I change something in Project A i just want to hit the run button and it should compile everything needed and start the main method in proectB.

I tried to use a parent project and used it as the main project in Netbeans:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.masr</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>


    <modules>
        <module>ProjectA</module>
        <module>ProjectB</module>
    </modules>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.projectB.Main</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

The Reactor plugin now checks for changes in the projects and compiles them if needed. However the exec-maven-plugin does not work here and has to be placed in Project B. But when I do this I need to run project B again.

If I set project B as the main project and hit the run button, Netbeans wont realize that it needs to recompile project A, if there are changes.

How can I make this work?

Comment: Netbeans by default do not resolve artifacts against the workspace as Eclipse with m2e.  You must install them to be visible to other modules.

Comment: Does this mean it is not possible for to compile and run everything automatically in Netbeans with one convenient click, without building more than necessary?